# Is there a simple way to remove a notification when it is clicked?

Tags: android

My service pops up a notification when localization services are not enabled them. When the user clicks he's redirected to the system prefs (from which I can't call cancel() from the notification manager).

Is there a simple way to remove a notification as soon as it is clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the flag: [`FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL) into notification.flags

Comment: Works, thank you.
`Notification notification = new Notification();` `notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;`